# Issue accessing child class getter from parent class although instance type matches

Tags: flutter, class, dart

I try to access a getter from the child class but its errors with `The getter 'test' isn't defined for the type 'Foo'`. While checking the type it recognizes the instance type correctly but when calling the getter it recognizes the type as the parent class type.

Any idea or suggestion?

```dart
class Foo {
  List<Foo> children = <Foo>[];

  void addChild(Foo child) {
    children.add(child);
  }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
  String get test => "Getter return value";
}

void main() {
  var foo = new Foo();
  var bar = new Bar();
  foo.addChild(bar);
  
  print(bar.test); //=> "Getter return value"
  print(foo.children.first); //=> Instance of 'Bar'
  print(foo.children.first.test); //=> Error
  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error states, there is no `test` getter defined on the base class (`Foo`).

> ```dart
> print(foo.children.first); //=> Instance of 'Bar'
> ```

That is the type known at *runtime*.  The type known at *compilation time* is the declared type: `Foo`.  The only guarantee is that `children` contains elements of type `Foo`.  It could have elements that were constructed by `Foo()` or elements of some other type that derives from `Foo` but not `Bar`.  There is no good way for the compiler to know that `foo.children.first` is actually a `Bar` without actually running your program.

So what can you do?

- Perform an explicit cast:

  ```dart
  print((foo.children.first as Bar).test);
  ```

  Note that this is *unsafe* since it will lead to an exception if `foo.children.first` isn't actually an instance of a `Bar`.
- Check the type at runtime:

  ```dart
  var element = foo.children.first;
  if (element is Bar) {
    print(element.test);
  }
  ```